# Bug na box com a informação do usuário na página da pergunta?

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Teve uma pergunta que eu fiz aqui, que foi editada pelo usuário @bigown.

Depois da edição, o quadrado que informa quem é o usuário que editou, empurrou o meu quadrado (o do meu usuário) para fora do contêiner da minha pegunta.

É possível corrigir isso aqui?

<kbd>[image: Notem a ferocidade com que o quadrado do Bigown empurra as minhas informações!]</kbd>

Comment: Eu acho que eu relatei esse problema também em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4814/3635 só ocorre após edições, usuário que não tem o botão "remover" pois ainda não tem o privilégio não vão notar o problema provavelmente.

Comment: O cara tem tanta reputação, que até empurra meu quadrado

Comment: hehehehe, realmente é impressionante, nem imagino chegar perto desta pontuação.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters reputação e medalhas também, tanto nas de prata quanto nas de bronze já estão no 3º dígito lol